# Object's property not available (undefined) inside Array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, iterator, undefined

I have a "photos" array of "photo" object.
Each "photo" object has a property value for the image url.

I try to iterate over the "photos" array with map(), in this way

```
photos.map((photo, index) => {
    console.log(photo)
    console.log(photo.value)
    return (
        <img
            key={index}
            src={photo.value}
            className={index === active ? 'active' : ''}
            alt="thumbnail"
        />
    )
})
```

For some reason that I'm completely missing, photo.value is not available.

This is what those two console.log print out:

[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE7E7.png)

It seems the object is available, but then the "value" property returns undefined.
 This was supposed to be very simple but I'm completely stuck at this point.

How can this be possible? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's `photo.photo.value`, you print the `photo` object, but that itself is an object with a "photo" property

Comment: Like pointed out by @Jayce444, the name of a callback value has no relation to the object,.  To save any confusion, it might be best to rename your `photo` callback parameter to say `item`, then you would have `item.photo.value`, and that would just make more sense, than `photo.photo`.  Alternatively you could destructure the photo param,.. `photos.map(({photo}, index) =>`

Comment: really don't know how did I miss this... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access value like this `photo.photo.value`

```
photos.map((photo, index) => {
    console.log(photo)
    console.log(photo.photo.value)
    return (
        <img
            key={index}
            src={photo.photo.value}
            className={index === active ? 'active' : ''}
            alt="thumbnail"
        />
    )
})
```